# MySQL Error 1064 for Table Creation

Tags: mysql

I am getting this error: Error in query (1064): Syntax error near 'utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, `Vendor` text collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL, ' at line 6

I have tried deleting line 6 and I am getting the same error in a different place.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wifiScan` (
  `ID_frame` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `TimeStamp` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `MAC` varchar(17) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `AP` text collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `RSSI` varchar(3) utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Vendor` text collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`ID_frame`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 6:

```
`RSSI` varchar(3) utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
```

Should be...

```
`RSSI` varchar(3) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
```

Comment: thank you - how could I have known this on my own? it seems pretty random which ones have COLLATE and which ones don't

Comment: @Barnaby, you write script and miss a keyword, isn't it?

Comment: Well, they all have it... `utf8_unicode_ci` is a collation, so it *always* has to be preceded by `COLLATE`, sort of like `utf8` is preceded by `CHARSET` (because it's a character set).  Your confusion is probably mostly from the error message, which is showing you the next few tokens *after* the point where the parser found something unexpected.